# Simple regex for words after another in java

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex that give me word after another word. 
For example:

```
street address Maria and another st. lohberg and give me another av. darrwerg and another st example
```

the desired output would be:

```
maria,lohberg,darrwerd,example
```

Maybye if there was a regex that could solve this situation: `address: herman poortstrat this is text but not address` give me: `herman poortstrat` But it is more complicated than that in my opinion.
I have the following regex: `(?<=\bstreet\s)(\w+)` But it gives me only address after street with whitespace.
 My regex give me text after "street" so it could be one of solutions but i need more words like: `"av.","av","av ","address"`and other combinations.
Generally I want to get from text only the street name and nothing else. Not the street and its number only the street. I'm not good in regex yet, so i'm asking for your help.

Comment: Given your current description, there's no way to distinguish between two word streets (like `Santa Maria`) and a one word street followed by another word (like `darrwerg and`)

Comment: I think similarly, so I want get only one word like darrwerg, or if I had address santa maria i want santa since i know that get santa maria is impossible.

Comment: Use [`\b(?:street\s+address|(?:av|st)\.?)\s+(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/c7MQ2e/2). See http://ideone.com/mrqkEN.

Comment: @Alcwak You should consider my answer. The other answer will not match if an address name is followed wirth punctuation or is at the end of the string. I updated the answer to account for an optional whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the words after *address*, *st.* or *av.* 
You can tweak it for you needs

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "street address Santa Maria and another st. lohberg and give me another av. darrwerg and another st street";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((address|st\\.|av\\.)\\s)(\\w+?\\s)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    List<String> streets = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        streets.add(m.group(3));
    }
    System.out.println(streets);
}
```

Comment: It works Almost perfect but in one situation worse, if i have: `st.lohberg` this regex avoid lohberg

Comment: Then make the space `\\s` optional by adding `?` at the end of it. So the final regex will be `"((address|st\\.|av\\.)\\s?)(\\w+?\\s)"`

Comment: Cool. It takes the words multiple times after the search pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
\b(?:street\s+address|(?:av|st)\b\.?)\s*(\w+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c7MQ2e/4)

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?:street\s+address|(?:av|st)\b\.?)` - a non-capturing group matching

  - `street\s+address` - `street`, 1+ whitespaces, `address`
  - `|` - or
  - `(?:av|st)\b\.?` - `av` or `st` **as whole words** followed with an optional dot
- `\s*` - *0 or more whitespaces*
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/hRiz9n):

```
String s = "street address Maria and another st. lohberg and give me another av. darrwerg and another st example";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:street\\s+address|(?:av|st)\\b\\.?)\\s*(\\w+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()){
    System.out.println("Value: " + m.group(1));
}
```

Results:

```
Value: Maria
Value: lohberg
Value: darrwerg
Value: example
```

Comment: I don't know why but in this site [link](https://regex101.com/r/vY9eY5/14) it don't work corretly

Comment: @Alcwak You did not enable `g`  and `i` flags - [see this demo from my answer](https://regex101.com/r/c7MQ2e/3).

Comment: Thanks, another what i find in my program when i have: `street address Maria and another st. lohberg and give me another av. darrwerg and another st example street exstreet and this is end` otuput is: `Value: Maria
Value: lohberg
Value: darrwerg
Value: example
Value: reet
` The last " reet" is wrong it should be exstreet

Comment: @Alcwak That happened because you said that there can be zero whitespace between the keyword and the value. You will need a word boundary - [`\b(?:street\s+address|(?:av|st)\b\.?)\s*(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/c7MQ2e/4).

Comment: This is much better as it ignores multiple spaces. Cool.